# AWS cognito "remember me" option

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, refresh-token, react-native-web

I have a react native and a react native web frontend application with an AWS backend.
For authentication I use AWS Cognito.
Some of my users use a public computer, so for those users the authentication tokens should expire within an hour (if they set the "remember me" option to false during login).

## the problem

- I cannot change the refresh token expiration to 60 minutes in AWS, because then all of my users are affected (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63533330/9611924).
  [image]
- There is [documentation on AWS cognito about "Tracking and Remembering Devices Using Amazon Cognito"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/tracking-and-remembering-devices-using-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/), however this is only relevant for 2FA.
- Another option would be to monitor (in the frontend) when you created the tokens and logout after 1 hour, but that would mean that a hacker (who has access to the computer) could access the authentication tokens before logout is initiated.

## AWS amplify

Although AWS amplify is a high level library that doesn't leave much room for customisation, I could just drop the refresh token?
[image]

Is this a valid option? And more importantly, a secure option?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the access, ID, or refresh token's lifetime in the request to the `/oauth2/token` endpoint, like it's seemingly possible with other IdPs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

> If the refresh token is expired, your app user must re-authenticate by
> signing in again to your user pool.

Depending on the security profile of your application, you shouldn't specify a low refresh token expiration, as it hurts the user's experience:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token.html

You cannot manipulate the expiration time of [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to delete them, either at a specified time or when the browser is closed, as they are configured as *HttpOnly* and *Secure*:

> You can also add an expiry date (in UTC time). By default, the cookie
> is deleted when the browser is closed:

Are you sure the tokens are stored as cookies? Normally they're stored in local- or session storage. If so, they can be deleted client-side using JavaScript. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71382557/aws-cognito-tokens-automatically-get-stored-in-local-storage-how-to-save-them) shows, that you can configure the Amplify library to store the tokens in session storage, i.e. they will be deleted, when the browser tab is closed:

```
Auth.configure({ storage: window.sessionStorage })
```

Finally, you might want to revoke the user's refresh token. This can be accomplished solely using the access token:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token.html#amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-revoking-all-tokens-for-user

Comment: Cookie was a typo, it should've been localStorage.
I ended up switching to sessionStorage, but I still want the session to expire if the users leaves his tabs open for a long time.
What do you propose for a react native application where sessionStorage is not applicable?

Regarding revoking the refresh token, this will also revokes the access token (and so immediate access), there isn't a way to set a delayed expire.

Comment: No, there is no option to set a delayed expire, like **expire this refresh token within 30 mins**. Have you ever visited a web application that detects user inactivity, and tells you that your session will expire within N mins, if you don't take action? You need to implement this yourself, and on user inactivity for N minutes, delete the tokens and sign the user out

Comment: I see, but what about smartphone applications (react native)? Should I delete the refresh token after login in smartphone applications?

Comment: For smartphone applications, you could delete the refresh token to restrict the session to the access token's lifetime. But, I don't consider a smartphone to be a shared device, like a public computer. Anyway, you could probably implement session inactivity detection on a smartphone too. What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: regarding session inactivity detection, if a user closes the application on his device (let's say a shared ipad in an organisation) then the session inactivity detection will not be running. If someone with ill intentions opens the app after a long time of inactivity and the new user attaches a debugger then he could read the tokens before the inactivity detection is able to delete the tokens

Comment: I think there are callbacks you can register for the app lifecycle (Android/iOS), so that whenever the app is backgrounded, you can delete its tokens :)